# How do I get the size of the screen?

Tags: c++, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I want to know the width of the screen to set my popup's width in a Win8 App.

Comment: Did you mean to say "width" of the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean the height and width of the screen (or more exactly the height and width of the application window), you can get that from [Window.Bounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.bounds.aspx#Y0)

For example, here's code behind a button what will display the current window's width in a text box on that window:

```
void App68::MainPage::Button_Click_1(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    txtWidth->Text = Window::Current->Bounds.Width.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to use Window.Bounds.Windows::UI::Xaml::Window::Bounds??

Comment: Thank you,Jim.C++ is difficult for me.I like C#= =

Comment: Because I want to learn directx3D.My schoolmate and I want to develop a little game engine.